# DI Error .Net Core 6 using Transient lifetime service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a problem trying to registrate a service using transients on .Net Core 6, I researched a lot... but I can't understood my mistake :(
This is the error message:

[image: Exception]

And I have the following code:

Program.cs

```
using Backend_LEGALTECH;

WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

.RegisterServices()
.Build()
.SetupMiddleware()
.Run();
```

RegisterStartupMiddleware.cs

```
 public static class RegisterStartupMiddlewares
 {
   public static WebApplication SetupMiddleware(this WebApplication app)
   {
       // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseSwagger();
           app.UseSwaggerUI();
       }

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();

       app.UseAuthorization();

       app.MapControllers();

       return app;
   }
}
```

RegisterStartupService.cs

```
public static class RegisterStartupServices
{
    public static WebApplicationBuilder RegisterServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<UpsilonLegaltechDBContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
            .GetConnectionString("Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=FakeDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=FakeUser;Password=FakePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;")));
        
        //CRASH HERE!
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimRepository, ClaimRepository>();  
        
        return builder;
    }
}
```

This is the IClaimRepository file:

```
public interface IClaimRepository : IBaseRepository<Claim>
{
    Claim GetClaimById(int id);
}
```

And the ClaimRepository file:

```
public class ClaimRepository : BaseRepository<Claim>, IClaimRepository
{
    public ClaimRepository(UpsilonLegaltechDBContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public Claim GetClaimById(int id)
    {
        return GetById(id);
    }
}
```

IBaseRepository and BaseRepository:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    void Add(T entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    void LogicRemove(T entity);
    void Activate(T entity);
    void Create(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly UpsilonLegaltechDBContext Context;
    public BaseRepository(UpsilonLegaltechDBContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().AddRange(entities);
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Where(expression);
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entities);
    }

    public void LogicRemove(T entity)
    {
        
    }

    public void Activate(T entity)
    {
        
    }
    public void Create(T entity)
    {

    }
    public void Update(T entity)
    {

    }
}
```

I am sorry I posted a lot of code, but... for me the code is correct, at least I worked with this kind of architecture and transients using a ConfigureService method, but I don't know why is not working on .Net Core 6 :(

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDITED (Thanks GH DevOps!):**

My DbContext (self generated):

```
public partial class UpsilonLegaltechContext : DbContext
{
public UpsilonLegaltechContext()
{
}

public UpsilonLegaltechContext(DbContextOptions<UpsilonLegaltechContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public virtual DbSet<Claim> Claims { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=FakeDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=FakeUser;Password=FakePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Claim>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.IdClaim);

        entity.ToTable("Claim");

        entity.Property(e => e.IdClaim)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasColumnName("idClaim");
        entity.Property(e => e.Age)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnName("age");
        entity.Property(e => e.Dni)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnName("dni");
        entity.Property(e => e.FirstSurname)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnName("firstSurname");
        entity.Property(e => e.Genre).HasColumnName("genre");
        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnName("name");
        entity.Property(e => e.SecondSurname)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnName("secondSurname");
    });

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}

partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

}

**EDITED: ( Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos!)**

Exception throwed (copied from Swagger):

Error: response status is 500

Response body
Download

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'FAKE_Services.Interfaces.IClaimService' while attempting to activate 'FAKE_API.Controllers.ClaimController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Is your DbContext injected?

Comment: I think so. Thanks @GHDevOps, I posted my DbContext too...

Comment: DbContext has scoped lifetime, so maybe you need to use scoped instead of transient lifetime. Also your `RegisterServices` method needs to register the DbContext using the `AddDbContext` method.

Comment: Like Fred said.

Comment: It is very strange place for the exception - I was not able to repro `builder.Services.AddTransient` throwing.

Comment: Sorry, I had the AddDbContext method in the RegisterServices, but I removed by error when I posted the code. So the DbContext is injected. @Fred I tried using  AddScope instead AddTransient but doesn't work :(

Comment: All this code *breaks* EF Core by putting a low-level repository on top of EF Core's higher level features. A DbSet is already a single-entity repository, a DbContext is already a multi-entity repository *and* unit of work. It's not a database connection - that's what ADO.NET is for.

Comment: Please post the actual exception text, not an image. You can get that by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup or with `Exception.ToString()`. The small part of the exception that's visible complains that `ClaimsRepository` is asking for a raw DbContext. Did you post the *actual* code that produces the error? How come `BaseRepository<T>` have a hard-coded `UpsilonLegaltechDBContext` parameter?

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the post with exception. My apollogies for the image.

Comment: In any case, all those "repositories" (they're DAOs, not repositories) only increase complexity, offering neither abstraction nor testability. An *actual* Repository is meant to allow you to work with data the same way you would with objects. ORMs like EF Core give you that. What's left is encapsulating high-level, type/scenario specific functionality that makes it easier to load entire graphs (eg a Blog and its posts), or encapsulate queries, eager loading code etc

Comment: That's not the exception in the image. There's a `Copy Details` in that exception popup which contains the actual exception, any inner exceptions and their stack trace. What you posted is a Swagger page with a different text

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, that's true, but I have this legacy code... I can't change it... so sad, really sad.

Comment: Post the actual exception at least. The image says `Unable to resolve service for type DbContext while attemptint to activate type ClaimsRepository`. That's not in the text you posted, that's what the Controller would return after the original exception. That doesn't match the code you posted

Comment: If the legacy code throws that, it has to be changed because it never worked. Not unless someone registered a *single* repository as a DbContext. The only way someone would do that would be to cover up just this kind of exceptions. Doing this though would mean it would be *impossible* to use more than one DbContext per application. Only small applications would get away with this. You'd have to replicate the bugs in exactly the correct order to get a running application too

Comment: Thanks again @PanagiotisKanavos, I edited the post withe the current exception, ystem.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type...

Comment: In this case, assuming there's only a single DbContext for the entire application, you could get this to work if you registered that DbContext as an implementation of DbContext with eg `.AddScoped<DbContext,UpsilonLegaltechDBContext>`. That's a *very* dirty hack though whose only job is to cover up the constructor that requires a raw DbContext.

Comment: You keep posting a different exception that has nothing to do with the exception in the image. Debug your code and when you hit the exception, look for the `Copy Details` text in the exception popup.

Comment: You need to register `IClaimService`. Example `builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimService, ClaimService>();`